# iPhone Server with Unique Key Access?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Now I am exceptionally new to network programming so tell me if this is a bad idea.

In my iPhone app I want to have a bunch of data which I can let me friends access via having the app on their phone as well.

So is it possible to have for example, me with my data, then I give a unique key to my friends, they put that into their app and they can now see my data. And people all over the world whoever owns said app can do the same, sharing data with friends via a unique key.

Love to know your thoughts and if it's a good idea, how could I achieve it?
If its a bad idea, what other approach would you suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: If devices are connected to the same WiFi network.

Comment: Users won't be n the same wifi sadly, they could be anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you would like to do, but I think you could look into asymmetric  cryptography, and specifically use a [public key/private key scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).